Is it possible to reduce the range of an RF controller?
I recently purchased a set of outdoor RGBW LED mini lights that came with a remote control to configure the color settings for each light.
With all the lights on, it is hard to change the color of only one light since the RF remote broadcasts a signal broadly enough to hit two or three other lights and change their color too. I’m wondering if anyone has advice on how to better “aim” or limit the strength of the RF signal to more easily direct or control just one light at a time. Any ideas?
ANSWER: After removing as much antenna from the remote as possible (as pictured), I saw a decrease in about 15 feet of range. After wrapping the receiver about 15 times, I saw another decrease in range of about 5 feet. I'm still about 15' away from the receivers.
What worked? One layer of aluminum foil over the remote everywhere besides a 1" gap near the top. This gave me roughly a 2-3' range allowing me to change receivers that are relatively close in proximity. Thank you so much everyone for your time and suggestions. I still don't understand why aluminum foil over the receivers didn't work, but over the remote did.
Here is the remote model for reference: XDJ-TX1021A-VER3.0
I've got multiple controllers, and quickly opened this one up for a better view.
Edit/update: On Q1 it reads "R25".
Front of the remote

Back of the remote

Update: Here are my (futile) attempts so far, do I need to be removing the entire antenna behind where I'm cutting, or is disrupting the connection good enough?

Furthest progress

Update: Is the section west out of R433 part of the antenna as well? I will begin experimenting with aluminum foil.

This question is not about amateur radio or the technology of radio, within the scope defined in the help center.

@MarcusMüller This is about an RF oscillator (QRPpp) and an antenna.

yes, but it's not about about amateur radio in specific, nor about the general theory of radio electronics – it's about changing the operation of a specific, non-amateur radio emitter. I think you interpreted the question as "how, in general, could I reduce the reach of a small radio emitter", which I can see as interpretation, but I'll have to honestly say that I think the asker really wants us to help him to modify this specific emitter, and that would put the question out of scope. I do understand, and do value your interpretation, though.

The new photo looks good. Is that still not weak enough??  My answer updated.

If that cutting doesn't reduce the range... How about adding a resistor in series with the battery (spring terminal). Try 1k or so? Otherwise more and more tinfoil, inside the case, (after some insulation tape to prevent shorts)

@tomnexus if this were my project, I would cut a pattern leading to C2 in the oscillator's supply and insert a series resistor there. However, that can make oscillation sluggish or unreliable and may cease to function as a remote altogether before the signal becomes weak enough. I would not put a series resistor on the battery because we have no good way to know where the logic chip begins to malfunction.

It is not,  I've even gone further back than the picture shows. It seems to have reduced the range by about 15 feet. I'm hoping I can reduce it by another 15 feet or so.

Updated the comment again. Try different ways to hold the remote. Cover the area with your hand while pressing the button. Also, try tinfoil. Try to cut a large piece and cover as much of a remote as possible. If not enough, you should also compromise the receiver sensitivity.

West of that point is a tank / feedback circuit, and you cannot remove that pattern, or it'll cease to function altogether. However, that part is now primarily radiating after removing the entire antenna.

Updated once again. A spray that you can use after the tin fol solution works to satisfaction.

Please don't forget to upvote and select my answer...

Did you try covering each receiver with tin foil? You could also cover both the receiver and the controller in tin foil. If the foil completely blocks the signal, cut it smaller and cover less. Trial and error may be necessary. Then, you can walk very close to each receiver to control them individually.
If tin foil works but you want an inconspicuous solution, there are "black wrap" or matte black "cinefoil" made for photographic or cinematographic lighting work. They are essentially metal foil painted black and come in rolls. If you are doing a lighting project, those might be handy.
EDIT/UPDATE after you posted the photo. The trace along the southern edge of the PCB may be a feedback/tank circuit, and the one along the eastern and northern edges is the actual antenna. We could discuss cutting a section of it or somehow compromising that antenna, but if the tinfoil approach works, that would be at least a reversible way to do it. Also, it is better to reduce the receiver's sensitivity, at least in part, rather than relying entirely on radiating less effective power.
The schematic diagram of the oscillator part is below. Q1 (SOT23 transistor marked R25) is 2SC3356, an old generation npn bipolar transistor for RF small signal applications made by NEC (now Renesas) since 1980s... although the one used may be one of Chinese copies, perhaps from Evvo Semi (the original has long been discontinued). The crystal oscillator, marked R433 is typically a SAW resonator for 433.92MHz, but this one comes in a regular crystal-like package. If it's really a 433MHz resonator, the oscillator is operating at a fundamental. If crystal, it must be an overtone oscillation. The circuit is Pierce CB topology. With a large R1, the oscillation is kept very weak, while the collector tank circuit gives feedback to the emitter at the desired transmission frequency.
The baseband signal for the device control is probably on the V+ or "Gnd" indicated in the diagram to modulate the carrier. Probably on-off keying (ASK).

As indicated in the diagram, trim the antenna pattern a bit at a time until the transmission becomes weak enough. Depending on how weak you want, you might be trimming past C3 (proximal to Q1, but be careful not to damage the collector tank circuit). I would use an acrylic/plexiglass cutting knife for this type of work, but a regular Xacto knife or other small snap-off blade knives would be ok. Just be careful.
Your new photo indicating the pattern disruption looks good. Is it still not weak enough?? Try cut here:

If that's not weak enough, the radiation from the tank/feedback "inductor" pattern left to that point is already significant. You can't remove that. Time to use tin foil. You'll have to experiment the size of the foil and how to cover the remote. Also, how you hold the remote (especially after chopping off the antenna like you did) would have a big impact on the transmission strength. If you cover the bottom end of the remote (where the oscillator circuit is) while pressing the button, I think it should be significantly weaker.
Once you figure out tin foil is good enough but want to make it neater, you can spray this inside the remote's plastic shell case:
https://mgchemicals.com/products/conductive-paint/conductive-spray-paint/emi-shielding/
Make sure you experiment with tin foil first, and also use care not to short anything as a result of spraying. Protect places that may touch the battery or any part of the circuit with a tape.

I still don't understand why aluminum foil over the receivers didn't work, but over the remote did.

One thing is that, your reciever probably had a wire leading to the power and/or the light. Without looking at the whole setup closely, it is hard to say anything definitively, but it is likely that those wires are acting as an antenna, at least partially, so that when you cover the receiver in tin foil, the signal still got in.
What we discussed in this Q&A is more like the electromagnetic interference (EMI) or noise emission reduction technique than amateur radio (when did I hear people complaining that the signal wasn't weak enough in amateur radio last time?), but it is still an important RF engineering skill.

I did try very briefly with a cheap tin foil from the store, I will test this a bit more to see if that's the best solution.

***EDIT/UPDATE I would love any tips on trying to cut a section or compromising the antenna, I have about 10 remotes to run tests on and only need one to control everything. What would you recommend?

@SeanDavies Sure, I have a pretty good idea, but to minimize room for incorrect info, can you give me the marking on Q1 (SOT23 transistor) and the crystal? It's not clear in the photo. You probably need a good loupe under good light to read them. Also, can you include the dimensions of the board, and maybe the photo on the other side?

Rather than a compromise antenna, maybe making it directional would help.

@user10489 Not necessarily. In real-life situations, there are a lot of reflections, and the beam pattern will not look like one in free space or ideal deployment far above the ground. Plus, this is probably in lower UHF so that a directional antenna would be too huge for a small remote controller.

I think something like a horn or cantenna (and maybe some attenuation to mitigate multipath) could work, but in retrospect, it would be pretty silly to try to use a remote while it is in a horn.
